# I want to display the text when you hit enter using IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

I have a text box that takes input and when i hit enter it stores the output and displays in an unordered list format. The function without IIFE works when i use onclick event. However, with IIFE its not functioning. Please help.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>messagewithenter</title>
</head>

<body>

Message:
<input type="text" name="message" id="message">
<input type="submit" value="add" id="submitenter" style="display: none">

<ul id="list"></ul>

<script>    

    (function () {

        var link = document.getElementById("submitenter");
        link.addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.onkeypress = enter;
            function enter(e) {
                if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
                    addMessage();
                }
            }
        });
        function addMessage() {
            var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            var output = "<li>" + message + "<li" + "<br>";

            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += output;

        }
    }());

   </script>

</body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were binding the event on click event of an invisible element, simply make it

```
document.onkeypress = enter;

function enter(e) {
  if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
    addMessage();
  }
}
```

**Demo**

```js
document.onkeypress = enter;

function enter(e) {
  if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
    addMessage();
  }
}

function addMessage() {
  var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
  var output = "<li>" + message + "<li" + "<br>";

  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += output;

}
```

```html
Message:
<input type="text" name="message" id="message">
<input type="submit" value="add" id="submitenter" style="display: none">

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: You can wrap it in IIFE, it won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    link.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.onkeypress = enter;
        ...
```

This code is flawed because if it works, it would reset the `document.onkeypress` event handler every time you click in the input box.

It's also unnecessary, as you can set that `onkeypress` handler without needing the click event. The whole thing can be written like this:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        addMessage();
    }
}
```

No need for the click handler at all.